# mvc redirect all request in action control to other action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want all request from localhost/Other_Data move to localhost/Other_Data/index2?id_Mode=1&city="ddd"
but I don't love use redirection I want use routing
may be help me...
thanks

```
public class SupperController: Controller
{

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
...
    } 
}

public class Other_Data:SupperController
{

    public ActionResult Index2(int Id_Mode, string city)
    {
....
..
    } 
}

....
..
.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default1",
            url: "Other_Data/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Other_Data", action = "Index2", Id_Mode = 1, city="ddd"}
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute("Other_Data" , "Other_Data/index2/{id_Mode}/{city}" , 
 new { controller = "Other_Data", action = "index2",id_Mode=1,city="ddd" });
```

Comment: no true
after test move to action Index
must going to action Index2 automatically

Comment: When you will call OtherData, then It will move on Index2, else not